# How get different lenght of splitted string "/" and "/something"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I split the string `"/"` and `"/something"` with `.split("/")` and i wanna get length, but its same : 2. How i can distinguish this? Ideally `"/".length == 0` and `"./something" == 1`
Any tips ?

Comment: please share the string

Comment: Can you post the code necessary to reproduce the issue ??

Comment: `pathName.split("/").length` returns 2, and `let pathName= "/" `

Comment: yes, "/" will split into two empy strings ... "/something" will split into ["", "something"] - thankfully this is how split works - if you want to ignore empty strings (es2015 example)... `var x = "/something".split("/").filter(e => e.length);`

Comment: @JaromandaX but in this way it returns only string not value of length

Comment: each string in the returned array has a length, and the returned array itself has a length - I'm not sure I understand what you expect as a result of a split

Comment: but i want only number of items in array except emty strings

Comment: oh, then `var x = "/something".split("/").filter(e => e.length).length`

Comment: it seems little complex but it works, thanks a lot :D :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string MUST have a / to register 1

```
var countThem = function countThem0(str, sep) {
    return str.indexOf(sep) < 0 ? 0 : str.split(sep).filter(function (e) {
        return e.length;
    }).length;
};
```

Otherwise

```
var countThem = function countThem(str, sep) {
    return str.split(sep).filter(function (e) {
        return e.length;
    }).length;
};
```

In ES2015, it's even neater

```
let countThem = (str, sep) => str.indexOf(sep) < 0 ? 0 : str.split(sep).filter(e => e.length).length;
```

or

```
let countThem = (str, sep) => str.split(sep).filter(e => e.length).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an empty String is falsy, you can use `!""` to decide whether or not you count that String:

```js
function myFunc(str){
  var parts = str.split('/'),
      i = 0;
  while(i<parts.length){
    // if the current String is empty, remove it from the array
    if(!parts[i]) parts.splice(i, 1);
    else i++;
  }
  return parts.length;
}

console.log( myFunc('zero') );    // 0
console.log( myFunc('/') );       // 0
console.log( myFunc('/one') );    // 1
console.log( myFunc('one/two') ); // 2
console.log( myFunc('1/2/3///') );// 3
```

You can also use `filter` to... filter those elements:

```js
function myFunc(str){
  return str.split('/').filter(function(part){return !!part}).length;
}

console.log( myFunc('zero') );    // 0
console.log( myFunc('/') );       // 0
console.log( myFunc('/one') );    // 1
console.log( myFunc('one/two') ); // 2
console.log( myFunc('1/2/3///') );// 3
```

Comment: There is no something more simple??

Comment: shouldn't `myFunc("zero")` result be 1?

Comment: @JaromandaX You might be right, I thought he might want 0 if the String does not contain any slash, but that would make sense to return 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this ways.

```
var str = "/";

str.split('/').join('') // always "" which equal false if there is only '/'

var str1 = "/somthing";

str1.split('/').join('')  // always non-empty if string not contain only '/' character
```